# Laravel Eloquent pegar somente um campo de um registro

Tags: php, laravel

Sou novo no laravel e estou com um probleminha

```
$profile_id = Profile::where("customer_id",$data["customer_id"])->where('is_default', 1)->select('id')->first()->get();
```

a partir desse consulta, como eu pego o campo `id`?

eu tentei

```
$profile_id->id
```

mas deu um erro

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vou ter que responder, porque outras pessoas já caíram nesse erro.

Existem duas classes que o `Laravel` pode retornar quando você faz uma consulta: `Collection` ou o model.

Quando se retorna o `Collection`, significa que você trouxe mais de um dado.

Quando retorna o `model`, significa que você trouxe um dado só.

Quando você usa o método `get` ao final da consulta, está trazendo vários resultados. Quando usa `first` ou `find`, está trazendo apenas um.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta teórica!

Answer (score 1):

Consegui!!

```
Profile::where("customer_id",$data["customer_id"])->where('is_default', 1)->select('id')->first()->id;
```